# passive afforestation

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

*Afforestation* is defined as 'the conversion of open land into forest by planting trees.'

What would be a synonym for *afforestation* if there is no human intervention involved?
Is there a one-word term for succession into forest?

Comment: Where is the "human" reference in the definition above? "Conversion" does not necessarily mean human involvement. See this definition: "Afforestation - Planting of trees in a methodical and planned manner and using them wisely ..." (http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090807233901AAUwdaS)

Comment: In the planting.

Answer (score 3):

I've come across ***spontaneous afforestation*** if that helps. Other terms include ***natural regeneration*** and ***natural reforestation***.

By the way, ***succession*** is supposed to be spontaneous.

Comment: succession is indeed spontaneous but can go in many more directions than just towards forest

Comment: Yes that's true - in that case I don't think there is a single word description.

Answer (score 1):

*Rewilding*

2.

to return (land) to a more natural state: rewilding an unpopulated island for use as an animal preserve.
from [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rewilding)

It still doesn't guarantee a passive process, but doesn't have the strong implication of human action that *afforestation* does.  It's (of course) not specifically about trees, though most uses seem to carry that implication.

Answer (score 1):

"Natural wild growth" is the idea you seem to be looking for but that's a phrase, not a single-word.

As opposed to cultivation/ afforestation, it is disuse that leads to natural wild growth.